# Confirm Password with jQuery Validate

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm trying to use jQuery validate plugin to confirm my password entry.

However, I don't want it to be a required field.

Just IF a user wants to change the password, they would need to confirm it.

If not, both fields shouldn't be validated.

```
jQuery('.validatedForm').validate({
    rules: {
        password: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 5
        },
        password_confirm: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 5,
            equalTo: "#password"
        }
    }
});
```

This is working perfectly, but again, both fields are required.

I would like to have this optional, in case someone just wants to change for instance their email or username and leave the password alone.

Comment: why don't you turn off: required: false?

Comment: yeah, i tried that, but then the confirmation doesn't work anymore.
i mean the password_confirm field IS required IF the password field isn't empty

Comment: oh, then I think you may need a custom validator: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod

Answer (score 177, accepted):

Remove the  `required: true` rule.

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w8r5za7s/)

```js
jQuery('.validatedForm').validate({
    rules: {
        password: {
            minlength: 5,
        },
        password_confirm: {
            minlength: 5,
            equalTo: "#password"
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: doesn't work. then it always says "please enter the same value again"
even though both fields are empty

Comment: please post the code. include jquery library version you are using in your sample. Cause here not work this solution!

Comment: @ratnakar it should work. ... edit the attached fiddle to recreate the issue

Comment: No its not working Arun ,Please review my code once 

            "user[password]": {
                minlength : 8
             },
             "user[password_confirmation]": {
                minlength : 8,
                equalTo: "#user_password"
             }

Comment: but we don't need a minlength for the second password I think, because however that equalTo rule will validate this case. Am I right?

Answer (score 39):

Just a quick chime in here to hopefully help others... Especially with the newer version (since this is 2 years old)...

Instead of having some static fields defined in JS, you can also use the `data-rule-*` attributes. You can use built-in rules as well as custom rules.

See http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/#link-list-of-built-in-validation-methods for built-in rules.

Example:

```
<p><label>Email: <input type="text" name="email" id="email" data-rule-email="true" required></label></p>
<p><label>Confirm Email: <input type="text" name="email" id="email_confirm" data-rule-email="true" data-rule-equalTo="#email" required></label></p>
```

Note the `data-rule-*` attributes.

Comment: This is better and easy answer than the first one,i like it, +1.

Comment: you can use data-msg-equalTo to change the default message

Comment: this is not working at all for me. Do I need to import some library or anything?

Answer (score 8):

It works if id value and name value are different:

```
<input type="password" class="form-control"name="password" id="mainpassword">
password: {     required: true,     } , 
cpassword: {required: true, equalTo: '#mainpassword' },
```

Answer (score 8):

```js
jQuery('.validatedForm').validate({
    rules: {
        password: {
            minlength: 5
        },
        password_confirm: {
            minlength: 5,
            equalTo: '[name="password"]'
        }
    }
});
```

In general, you will not use `id="password"` like this.
So, you can use `[name="password"]` instead of `"#password"`

Answer (score 3):

I'm implementing it in Play Framework and for me it worked like this:

1. Notice that I used data-rule-equalTo in input tag for the id inputPassword1.
   The code section of userform in my Modal:

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="pass1">@Messages("authentication.password")</label>
    <input class="form-control required" id="inputPassword1" placeholder="@Messages("authentication.password")" type="password" name="password" maxlength=10 minlength=5>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="pass2">@Messages("authentication.password2")</label>
    <input class="form-control required" data-rule-equalTo="#inputPassword1" id="inputPassword2" placeholder="@Messages("authentication.password")" type="password" name="password2">
</div>
```

2. Since I used validator within a Modal

```js
$(document).on("click", ".createUserModal", function() {
    $(this).find('#userform').validate({
        rules: {
            firstName: "required",
            lastName: "required",
            nationalId: {
                required: true,
                digits: true
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            optradio: "required",
            password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            password2: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        highlight: function(element) {
            $(element).parent().addClass('error')
        },
        unhighlight: function(element) {
            $(element).parent().removeClass('error')
        },
        onsubmit: true
    });
});
```

Hope it helps someone :).

Comment: Liking the highlight method :)

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>
   
     $(document).ready(function(){            
   
     });

     function login() {
        
         var password = $("#psw").val()
         var password1 = $("#psw1").val()
         var pswlen = password.length;
         if (pswlen < 8) {
             alert('minmum  8 characters needed')
         }
         else {

            if (password == password1) {
                 alert('continue');
                 window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
             }
             else {
                 alert('failed');
             }

         }

     }
    
</script>
```