# A Very Basic Confirm password validation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone solve this fiddle. it has two fields password and confirm password. Validation needs to be done such that both password entered should be the same.

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $('#EditForm').validate({ 
        rules: {
            password: {
                required: true
            },
            cpassword: {
                required: true,
                equalTo: "#password"
            }
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kalai789/aCZgK/2/

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to name your fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly the external version of jQuery you had loaded was very old (1.5.2) it appears incompatible with the current version of validate, I updated the fiddle to use 1.6.4 as that was the lowest available on jsFiddle. Secondly, the `rules` and other settings for the validate plugin are keyed on the `name` attribute of the element, not the `id`, so they need to be added:

```
<input type="password" name="password" id="password"/>
<input type="password" name="cpassword" value="" id="cpassword"/>
```

[**Working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/aCZgK/6/)

Answer (score 2):

use `keyup` method

http://jsfiddle.net/dbwMY/

check the info source
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9717796/1768043

Comment: thanks but i have been encouraged to use rules only . can you please solve that fiddle which i shared which is not working

Comment: @kalai: You need to actively run the check, when your input element changes. This is why X-Pippes used the keyup-Eventhandler, which then calls the check routine. You can not just "define" your checks... You have to actually run them, too.

Comment: PS: This behaviour might have changed in future revisions of jQuery, where the event handler (form-submit Event) is attached automatically.

Comment: Validating on keypress seems like overkill. It will tell they user what they have typed is invalid before they have finished, which could lead to confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Found [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14703374/jquery-validate-confirm-password)

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fEZFB/2/)

```
jQuery('.validatedForm').validate({
    rules : {
        password : {
            minlength : 5
        },
        password_confirm : {
            minlength : 5,
            equalTo : "#password"
        }
    }
});
```