# How develop function password in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, passwords

How develop function for password and confirmpassword in jquery,i want when i create confirm password, there is message show's "password and confirmpassword incorrect !" until the password and confirmpassword are the same and tnak's

Comment: Probably a duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14703374/confirm-password-with-jquery-validate

Comment: do you want a function to check password and confirm password ?

Answer (score 1):

If you need a function to validate password, try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    function validate_password(){
        var password = $('#password_field_id').val();
        var confirm_password = $('#confirm_password_field_id').val();
        if(password === confirm_password){
            //Do something if password matches
        }
        else{
            // alert something saying password don't match
        }
    }
});
```